# Java multi-threading threads terminating at random

Tags: java, string, multithreading, concurrency, terminate

While learning Java concurrency I ran into this behaviour which I can't explain:

```
public class ThreadInterferrence implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadInterferrence());
        t.start();
        append("1", 50);
        t.join();
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    private static String value = "";

    public void run() {
        append("2", 50);
    }

    private static void append(String what, int times) {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
            value = value + what;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the program generate random Strings? More importantly **why does the length of output vary**? shouldn't it always be exactly 100 chars?

Output examples:

```
22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
1111111111111111111111111111112121112211221111122222222222222
```

etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the topic of your updated question (why does the length of output vary? shouldn't it always be exactly 100 chars?)

The behavior will be unpredictable, since the re-assignment of the new String is not atomic. Note that Strings are immutable and you keep reassinging a value to a variable. So what is happening is one thread gets the value, the other thread also gets the value, one thread adds a character and writes it again but so does the other thread with the old value. Now you're losing data because the update from one of the threads is lost.

In such a case you could use a StringBuffer which is thread-safe, or add synchronization which I'm sure you'll learn about.

Answer (score 4):

Reason is you have two threads.

- Main thread which is appending to same value string
- ThreadInterferrence Thread which is appending again to same value String.

It's Operating System (OS) who is scheduling which thread to run when and hence you see random output. So in your case, OS schedules your runnable to run for a time being which prints 1 and then tries to run main thread which in turn prints 2.

Comment: Okay i follow you so far. But why does the length of the output String vary? Shouldn't it always be exactly 100 characters no matter the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

[Question] More importantly why does the length of output vary?

[Answer] The variable "value" is being used by multiple threads (Main thread as well as the other thread). Hence the method which is used to change the state of the variable needs to be thread safe to control the final length. That is not the case here.